# Get Location module Block : how to show map markers for particular taxonomy term - exposed to user

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, blocks, google-maps, views

I am using the [Get Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations) module for building store locator functionality in my site. I have made a content type with `field = address` and `field type = Geolocations` Fields with `widget = Geocoder`.

I also added one another field of term reference. I created nodes and enable getlocation search block. Markers for given locations are successfully displayed on "getlocations" block map but I need to filter taxonomy term data and need to use expose filter, So when user choose one term, it gives the results marker of corresponding term reference node.

I can't use view, because in this module, block is directly a module, it is not coming from any view. How can I use exposed filter that filter my nodes by taxonomy terms and displayed corresponding markers on map.